# MVC How to add a delay on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is pretty simple(i think, but i cant find any reference, who wants to slow down their site,right?) and may sound ridiculous, but what I am trying to do is to have a splash screen on page load of the Home/Index of my site.
What I did is at the top of my page, I just added a simple div for my splash and use javascript to hide it when the page is loaded.

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
// Remove splash screen after load
$('.splash').css('display', 'none')
})
```

but my problem is, my home index loads too fast (because its just plain text/html) hence the splash screen shows like .5 sec only. I want to add atleast 2-3 secs before it is removed, Im assuming I just need to add a line or two of code in my `$(window).bind` to pause for a couple of secs before doing `$('.splash').css('display', 'none')` but I dont know what or how to do it, please help! Thank you!

Comment: what you can do is to do a setTimeout(function(){}, 3000); after window load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` to delay things in Javascript, like this:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    var delay = 5000;

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.splash').css('display', 'none');
    }, delay);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response man, I knew its this simple! Now I need to wait 10mins before I can select this as the answer. wp.

Answer (score 1):

Timeout works.

`$(window).bind("load", function () {
    // Remove splash screen after load and 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.splash').css('display', 'none')
    }, 3000);
});`